# SQL is giving an error even though seems to be correct

Tags: mysql, sql

Giving an error, I was trying to see what's wrong, to no avail. Please help

```
 SELECT UserId, AVG(Total) AS AvgOrderTotal
FROM Invoices
HAVING COUNT(OrderId) >= 1
```

Comment: group by!!!!!!! and count should be one of the columns!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT UserId, AVG(Total) AS AvgOrderTotal
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(OrderId) >= 1
```

Assuming that `OrderId` is never `NULL`, the `HAVING` is redundant, so perhaps this is sufficient:

```
SELECT UserId, AVG(Total) AS AvgOrderTotal
FROM Invoices
GROUP BY UserId;
```